# Linking to Password Protected Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, passwords

Here is what I am trying to do. I've searched extensively with no success.
I have two **spreadhseets**.
Book1
Book2 with password to `open = "green"`

Book 1 has a formula in cell `A1 ='C:\[Book2.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1`

I want my macro to copy the formula in Book1 cell **A1 to A2** so that it picks up ref A2 from password protected Book2. The problem is that it keeps popping up to ask for the password. I want to enter that password automatically WITHOUT opening Book2. I can't get past the Password Pop up immediately after the new formula is pasted.

Any help much appreciated. Code I'm using so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    UpDateLinks

End Sub

Sub UpDateLinks()
    Const PWord As String = "green"
    Dim xlLinks
    Dim i As Integer
    xlLinks = ThisWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(xlLinks) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(xlLinks)
            SendKeys PWord & "{Enter}"
            ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=xlLinks(i)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Linking between workbooks is a recipe for disaster. My suggestion: put everything in the one book if you possibly can.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing currently but how do I make the information I am linking to (say in another tab) secure so that it cannot be linked to without some sort of permission/password?

Comment: Excel isn't too secure...Excel 2016 is *somewhat* secure, other versions are easily hacked. What kind of information are we talking about here, and how sensitive is it? Can you give more context about what it is this spreadsheet does?

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. One tab has client data. The other tab pulls that data in. But different users of the spreadsheet will be pulling in their client data only, knowing the names of only their clients. I want to prevent a user being able to freely 'see' or link to any cell in the client data sheet and just gain access to private information. Hope that makes sense. I am using Excel 2016. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I think you're going to have to segment the data by user. How many users do you have? They might need to each have their own spreadsheet, containing just their own clients. Not as hard to set up as it sounds, with the help of a little VBA. But a task like this is probably better suited to something secure with row-level security, such as PowerBI.

Comment: Also, where is the source data extracted from? A database such as SQL Server or Access? If your users are on the same network, might be possible to have their files connect directly to the database in order to suck out the information that they are allowed to access, as they need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with timing: the password dialog does not appear until you call `UpdateLink` (or write the formula with a link in it), and by that time your `SendKeys` is already long done and gone. On the other hand, once the password dialog is open then the VBA is stuck on that line, and Excel is effectively hung until someone or something enters the password and clicks ok (or Cancel, which causes UpdateLink to error).

So, you need to run something (a vbscript, an exe, or whatever) external to your Excel thread BEFORE you call UpdateLink (or write the formula). You will want to pass that 'something' your Excel instance handle, and the password it will need. I wrote an executable, which resulted in this VBA to call the exe and then call UpdateLink:

```
Public Sub UpdateLinksIntoPasswordProtectedWorkbook()
Const pwd As String = "WhateverThePwdIs"
'call the EXE passing the hWnd and the pwd
Shell """c:\SomeFolders\SpyUpdateLinkPwdDialog.exe"" " & Application.hWnd & " " & pwd
'set the new formula
Range("A2").Formula ="'C:\[Book2.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1"
'or alternatively in other situations call UpdateLink
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink "c:\Whatever\PasswordProtectedWorkbook.xlsx"
End Sub
```

The executable watches for the next 30 seconds for a child window of that Excel instance having the class 'bosa_sdm_XL9' (discovered this name using Spy++), and then populates the password into that dialog and clicks its OK button. Links are updated and the VBA can then carry on from there.

The executable was written using UIAutomation (more specifically, UIAComWrapper in the Windows Kit), to first set focus back to the Excel instance immediately, and then to query the children of that Excel instance every second for the next 30 seconds or so:

```
/* this is critical: switch focus back to the Excel instance that called me */
AutomationElement aeExcel = AutomationElement.FromHandle(Program.xlwHnd);
```

And then in a timed method:

```
/* the password dialog class name is bosa_sdm_XL9 */
AutomationElementCollection aeXLPwdWindow = aeExcel.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "bosa_sdm_XL9"));
if (aeXLPwdWindow.Count > 0)
        {
            AutomationElementCollection aePwdBox = aeXLPwdWindow[0].FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "EDTBX"));
            AutomationElementCollection aeOkButton = aeXLPwdWindow[0].FindAll(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "OK"));
            if (aePwdBox.Count > 0 && aeOkButton.Count > 0)
            {
                /* UIAutomation? couldn't get it to work */
                SendMessage(new IntPtr(aePwdBox [0].Current.NativeWindowHandle), WM_SETTEXT, 0, new StringBuilder(Program.pwd));
                object vp;
                /* UIAutomation click the button */
                if (aeOkButton[0].TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePatternIdentifiers.Pattern, out vp))
                {
                    ((InvokePattern)vp).Invoke();
                    attempts = 30; //stop trying after 30 seconds
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can sort of achieve this in a single workbook. Set the data sheet's visible property to xlVeryHidden and then set a password to the VBA. It is then not possible to unhide the sheet from the user interface

Comment: very hidden worksheets are still accesible from vba code or any formula, so it wouldn't be secure